# Increase text size without changing grid cell size tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

As part of a project I'm making, I have the following function that creates a grid of specified x and y cells:

```
def grid():
    x = 5
    z = 5
    for i in range(x * z):
        b = Label(letters, width=0, height=0,font=("Noto Sans SemiBold", 14), text=str(i)[0])
        b.grid(row=math.floor(i / x), column=i % x, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    for i in range(x):
        letters.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    for i in range(x + (z - x)):
        letters.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
```

This works fine except the text is too small on each cell (ignore the current text, my final will be similar to wordle in that each cell will contain a large letter). This is the current size

[image: Grid with text too small]

And this is what happens if I increase the text size:

[image: Grid with text too large]

Essentially, the spacing around each character remains the same meaning the text still doesn't adequately fill the boxes. As such, my question is how can I increase the size of the text without also increasing the size of the cells, so my characters fill each cell.

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with the various options for `Label` such as padding and borderwidth and highlightthickness?

Comment: I've tried those, but none of them seem to work, I may revert to using images, but they won't be very flexible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a 1x1 blank image and add this image to every label, then you can specify the `width` and `height` in pixels which not affected by the size of the font used:

```py
...
blank = PhotoImage()

def grid():
    x = 5
    z = 5
    for i in range(x * z):
        b = Label(letters, width=100, height=100, image=blank, font=("Noto Sans SemiBold", 24), text=str(i)[0], compound='c')
        b.grid(row=math.floor(i / x), column=i % x, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    for i in range(x):
        letters.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    for i in range(x + (z - x)):
        letters.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
...
```

Result of font size 24:

[image]

Result of font size 64:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works well and is much better than using images

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the `place()` geometry manager because it allows precise positioning.

```
import math
import tkinter as tk


def grid():
    x = 5
    z = 5

    fontsize = 64
    pad = 2
    cellsize = fontsize + pad
    font = ("Noto Sans SemiBold", -fontsize)  # Neg font size to set size in pixels.
    for i in range(x * z):
        b = tk.Label(letters, width=2, height=1, font=font, text=str(i)[0], relief='ridge')
        row, col = divmod(i, x)
        b.place(x=row*cellsize, y=col*cellsize)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
letters = tk.Frame(root)
letters.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Here's some screenshots showing the results of using different `fontsize` values:

`fontsize=24`:

[image: screenshot1]

`fontsize=64`:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, the letter grid is within another grid system that needs to be resizeable so using pixel positioning isn't really realistic. After discussing with some other people, I think I will just use images for each letter, which isn't ideal but will hopefully work.

Comment: FYI, in my example `letters` is a `Frame` and frames can be nested in other frame, so I think this would work for you. Also using images means you'll need to generate them for all the letters for potentially many different font sizes.

Comment: Yeah `letters` is also a Frame in my program, I tried implementing it and it didn't work so it may just be something to do with the way the rest of my grid is set up. I'll use the solution from acw1668 but thank you for taking the time to help me.